# GCP Cloud SQL HA mySQL, which public IP to connect?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-cluster, google-cloud-sql

Taken from this link: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#normal

[image]

After setup a 2nd generation mySQL failover instance in Cloud SQL, found that actually two IP addresses were provided, one for master, and another for failover instance.

From the picture above, how can we determine the "IP address X"? is it

1. a separated load balancer IP?
2. the IP of the master instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud SQL has 2 failover (HA) strategies

-- The newest strategy(that correspond to your diagram) does not offer a second public or private IP, you can't reach the standby instance.

-- The [legacy strategy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#legacy_mysql_high_availability_option) you have a second cloud sql instance(failover) that can be accessible from his own public and private IP

In both cases when you master instance has a failover event all traffic is [routed to the standby instance/failover replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-overview), using the same IPs and the same connection name.

Always use the master IP address.